# How to make a dynamic zooming timeline panel based on DateTime value in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, zooming, timeline

I have made a panel with static DateTime range on it and want to continue with the zoom feature which is dynamically changing the range time.

I had tried to look around on the internet, but just found about zooming to the panel (without dynamic range value of DateTime).

Is there anyone know how to do this in C# winforms? Or perhaps it will be great if anyone knows any reference about it?

Just want to make it more clear, here is the example:
This is my current timeline panel with the interval of 20 seconds :

[image: Timeline with 20 seconds range DateTime]

For example if I zoom it at the interval of 04:21:30 and and 04:21:50, the timeline interval should be smaller, (in 2 seconds for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was someone who voted and favorited my question, I will give the answer of my case.
At the end, I used the [MouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MouseUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx) events. With those events, I could calculate the scale of the pixel and the DateTime.

Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
int PressedCoordinate;
int ReleasedCoordinate;

private void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int PressedCoordinate = e.X;
        //in this part, calculate the DateTime based on the scale of pixel vs datetime
    }
}

private void Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int ReleasedCoordinate = e.X;
        //in this part, calculate the DateTime based on the scale of pixel vs datetime
        //calculate the range and do the zoom-in logic
    }
}
```

If you want to discuss the detail of it, don't hesitate to comment. Cheers!